# interaction with dummy variables in lm() in R

Tags: r

ref: http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-for-ecologists-putting-together-a-piecewise-regression/

In this paper, I am confused about this argument:

```
y ~ x*(x < breaks[i]) + x*(x>=breaks[i])
```

in `lm()`.

I know `*` in `lm` means interactions and main effects so does this mean that predictors are `x x (x < breaks[i]) (x < breaks[i])` and interactions?

Answer (score 1):

This is a method of doing "segmented" regression. You are essentially creating two different models, one for the section where x < breaks[i] and another where the opposite is true. In this case the `*` will be functioning as a multiplier rather than as an interaction operator because the values are {0,1} so there won't be a two level result. The webpage seems to do a pretty nice job of illustrating this, so it's unclear what is missing. The model formula might be more clear if it were written as:

```
y ~ x*I(x < breaks[i]) + x*I(x>=breaks[i])
```

It essentially means that there are two predictors: the first one being `x` and the second one being a logical vector that is 1 in the region less than breaks[i] and 0 in the other region. In fact you probably would not need two terms in the model if you just used:

```
 y ~ x*I(x < breaks[i])
```

I thought the predictions would be the same, but they were slightly different, perhaps because the two term model implicitly allowed completely independent intercepts.

There also are `segmented` and `strucchange` packages that support segmented regression.

Comment: Just got a downvote on this answer but the downvoting without an explanatory comment is unhelpful in improving SO unless the identified issue is obvious ... and it's not obvious to me.